# Element not fadingOut

Tags: jquery, hide, fadeout

I have 2 divs, that need to fade out once the element called "container" is visible, the problem is one of the elements, "navigation" fades out fine like its suppose to, but the element "backtotop" just seems to hide without a fade out.

I am not sure why this is happening, even if i put .fadeOut(3000) the element just delays before hiding, without fading out.

```
var startY = $('#container').position().top + $('#container').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(){
checkY();
});

function checkY(){
if( $(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
    $('#backToTop, #navigation').fadeIn(600);
}else{
    $('#backToTop, #navigation').fadeOut(600);
}
}

checkY();
```

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/69Dan/14/

this is basically the idea of it, but for some reason my jquery isnt working in jsfiddle, sorry I'm not too experienced with jsfiddle.

Comment: You have to select `jQuery 1.8.2` in the top left panel where it says `Choose Framework`. The default is Mootools: http://jsfiddle.net/69Dan/15/ I see both divs fade in and out though.

Comment: not to sure why it isn't working. I uploaded it to my host so you can take a look.

http://maximsiebert.com/coffee/index.html

Comment: I found the problem, I had a css transition effect on my backtotop div, which was causing the problem.