# alternative to (window).scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, fadein, fadeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ScrollTop really jerky in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222978/scrolltop-really-jerky-in-chrome)

I'm using the following code to get a back to top button and a navigation to fade in once the user scrolls. The problem is its triggering every time you scroll, therefore causing the scrolling to be really jerky. Is there an alternate way to do this, which would maybe trigger the function only once?

```
    $(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
            $('#backToTop, #navigation').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#backToTop, #navigation').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    }); 

   });
```

Comment: does `show()` and `hide()` suffice?

Comment: I already tried helping you with this in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13223630/594235).  Please do not post duplicates.   I politely asked you specific questions trying to narrow it down and you never described the goal you were trying to achieve.

Comment: it still causes it to be jerky whether its fadein or show

Comment: Where is your HTML?  Where is your functional description?

Comment: I don't know why you would only want to trigger it once...seems to defeat the purpose.

Comment: Scrolling in Chrome is jerky anyway...

Comment: @VIDesignz, see his original question and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13223630/594235).  IMHO, both questions need to be closed until he can at least provide a functional description and some HTML.

Comment: @Sparky672... Thats brilliant man! Wonder why this question was asked...again.

Comment: @VIDesignz, I thought my answer was detailed enough to get him going in the right direction, and for some reason the OP is ignoring requests to provide the HTML and a functional description.

Comment: And here is yet another piece of the same puzzle:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150396/element-not-fadingout

Comment: the problem with the answer you've provided is only once the user click the .recipes and .cookingRecipes does the backToTop and navigation divs fade in. so if the user were to scroll with his mouse wheel rather than clicking the links, those elements wouldn't fadeIn.

Also, once the elements fadeIn, the jerkyness comes back.

Comment: @Sparky Its tough answering for newcomers...appreciation is hard to come by these days.

Comment: @MaximSiebert, again, you talk about `.recipes` and `.cookingRecipes` as if I've seen your page and know what you're talking about.  Again, for the tenth time, **where is the HTML?**  Can you construct a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: http://maximsiebert.com/coffee/

I uploaded to my host so you could see.
this is with the code from your answer.

another problem is it doesn't fade out once you reach the top again.

-the jerkyness is on chrome, works fine on firefox.

Comment: @MaximSiebert, your link is giving me a 404 error.  However, you should not be expecting people to dig through your site.  Questions need to remain useful to others in the future.  So please post the HTML inside your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222978/scrolltop-really-jerky-in-chrome) and construct a [jsFiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe set a timeout...

```
function scrollit(){  
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
    $('#backToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
    $('#backToTop').fadeOut();
    }
     }

var timer;

$(window).scroll(function () {

window.clearTimeout(timer);
timer = window.setTimeout(function(){ scrollit(); }, 2000);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [Ben Alman's jQuery throttle or debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) plugin.  Basically this limits your functions to be run only a certain amount of times.  The difference between the two is explained on the website:

> Well, to put it simply: while throttling limits the execution of a
>   function to no more than once every delay milliseconds, debouncing
>   guarantees that the function will only ever be executed a single time
>   (given a specified threshhold).